# How to add datepicker and timepicker in a single popup with datetime format as yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ using ng-bootstrap?

Tags: angular, datetime, ng-bootstrap, iso8601

I am creating a form using bootstrap and angular. Here I want to add an input field for DateTime. I need a popup to select the date and time. I cannot understand how I can integrate the date picker and time picker together using ng-bootstrap. Also, I need the data to be sent in the following format "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ" after the user selects the date and time. The time has to be in 24hour format.

I want something like this. During selection preferred date format would be dd/mm/yyyy, but it's not very important. The only importance is on submitting the form the DateTime values should be sent to the server in this format "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ".

[image: datetime-popup]

Answer (score 0):

You could use PrimeNG (https://primefaces.org/primeng).

They have Calanders (https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/calendar) that pretty much do what you want. Also the documentation is quite good.

If you need further help, feel free to reply.